# Grails 3.3.9 Multitenacy database pooling issue

Tags: mysql, grails, connection-pooling

I am working on application based on grails multitenancy. Here we get pool size issue during heavy usage mostly in one database.
In mysql process list, there are many queries with high sleep values like (3774, 14774) and eventually they fill up all connections:

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wait_timeout | 28800 |
+---------------+-------+
```

**Will decreasing this value to lower time(eg: 10 min) will be good option in prod environment.**

**Also if any suggestions anyone can provide on mysql properties I need to change.**

```
Grails : 3.3.9
AWS RDS : m4.2xlarge
Engine : MySQL Community 5.7
Total database used in application = 38
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36'
```

Config in yml file :

```
grails:
    gorm:
        multiTenancy:
            mode: DATABASE
```

All other datasource config :

```
dataSourceNameOne:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:mysql://AWS_RDS_END_POINT:3306/dataSourceNameOne?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
                username: ####
                password: ####
                pooled: true
                jmxExport: true
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 5
                    maxActive: 30
                    minIdle: 8
                    maxIdle: 14
                    maxWait: 5000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQuery: SELECT 1
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                    defaultTransactionIsolation: 2
```

Config for database where pool connection issue occurs mostly, here made changes :

```
dataSourceNameWithTimeOutIssue:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:mysql://AWS_RDS_END_POINT:3306/dataSourceNameWithTimeOutIssue?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
                username: ####
                password: ####
                pooled: true
                jmxExport: true
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 5
                    maxActive: 120
                    minIdle: 8
                    maxIdle: 30
                    maxWait: 5000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQuery: SELECT 1
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                    defaultTransactionIsolation: 2
```

Comment: Decrease the number of "children" in the web server -- The value there apparently is bigger than `max_connections` in MySQL.  (Sleeping threads are not much of a problem.)

Comment: @RickJames For one database I will have 120+ connections eventually in sleep mode and after that start getting pool connection issue
Max Connection available for current RDS = 2730

Comment: Are there 120 users connected?  Or is this some kind of pooling that fails to close the connections?  Which component is doing the "connection pooling"?--the app?, the web server?  a proxy server?  mysql?  What is the value of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';`?  Of `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`?

Comment: there are not 120 users connected
 `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| max_connections | 2663  |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

polling from app

Comment: `Max_used_connections` would give the high-water-mark of the number of concurrent connections.